# Three.js object to array

Tags: javascript, arrays, three.js

I'm just beginner with Three.js. I would like to push my 'palmtree' object to an array. My code should be fine, I think..

I have my `var objects = [];`.

And inside the init:

```
var mtlLoader = new THREE.MTLLoader();
mtlLoader.load("objects/palmtree.mtl", function(materials) {
    materials.preload();
    var objLoader = new THREE.OBJLoader();
    objLoader.setMaterials(materials);
    objLoader.load("objects/palmtree.obj", function(palmtree) {
        palmtree.position.x = 205.12577753354344;
        palmtree.position.y = 2;
        palmtree.position.z = -600.0613083252872;
        palmtree.scale.x = 64;
        palmtree.scale.y = 64;
        palmtree.scale.z = 64;
        scene.add(palmtree);
        objects.push( palmtree );
    });
});
```

The result looks fine. I have my palmtree in the scene. But when I try `objects.length` I get 0.. I don't understand what is wrong.

How can I push my palmtree to the objects array? Many thanks.

Comment: Do you see the palmtree with all the adjustments you did (scaling and positioning)?

Comment: Yes, I see the palmtree correctly

Comment: did you check the length after the model was loaded?

Comment: Yes. I checked the length outside the objLoader.load (see answer of Wilt). If I check the length inside the objLoader.load then I get 1 as result. I'm now trying to figure out how I can check the length outside the objLoader.load with the palmtree in it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think your are missing something fundamental here. Object loading is an asynchronous process so if you call `objects.length` somewhere outside your callback method it will most likely return `0` for the array length since your palm tree has not been loaded yet.

But try once to check `objects.length` in the callback for example like this:

```
var mtlLoader = new THREE.MTLLoader();
mtlLoader.load("objects/palmtree.mtl", function(materials) {
    materials.preload();
    var objLoader = new THREE.OBJLoader();
    objLoader.setMaterials(materials);
    objLoader.load("objects/palmtree.obj", function(palmtree) {
        palmtree.position.x = 205.12577753354344;
        palmtree.position.y = 2;
        palmtree.position.z = -600.0613083252872;
        palmtree.scale.x = 64;
        palmtree.scale.y = 64;
        palmtree.scale.z = 64;
        scene.add(palmtree);
        objects.push( palmtree );
        console.log(objects.length); // <-- will output new length
    });
});
```

In this case it will output `1`.

So the array length will only return `1` after your loading process has finished and the callback has been executed.

Comment: Thanks. This is really helpful. Now I have to figure out how I reach it from outside the load.

Comment: @EmielSchumacher You can reach it the same way, the question is more about when you use this array. What do you want to do with this array?

Comment: I want to check if I click on an object in the onDocumentMouseDown function  with raycaster.intersectObjects( objects ). That is why it needs to be in the array. :-)

Comment: @EmielSchumacher it will be in the array after load is done, so you can use this code without problems.